# Escape key doesn't clear direct reply bubble while suspended

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, notifications, account-suspension

(not sure if bug or not)

I recently had a 30 minute suspension. You can still be replied to while suspended, which pops up a little orange bubble-counter.

Under normal use, you can press escape while in the chat box to clear all of them.

While suspended, there is no chat box, and thus escape doesn't do anything.

1. I'd like escape to clear those chat notifications while suspended
   1.a. is it supposed to do that already?

Comment: I assume this is a edge case that has never been handled. Things not working for suspended users probably isn't a priority since most suspended users won't be trying to use the site.